# Duplicate subdirectory in path aliases

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I have an odd bug that isn't on other drupal install for other domains on my server.

Basically, menus work fine.

However links in the content will look like this:

```
https://example.com/content/content/node/123
```

instead of this

```
https://example.com/content/node/123
```

which is how it should be.

Interestingly enough this persists in using the `l()` function in Drupal 7 templates or in views even if I use rewrite output.

This doesn't happen on another Drupal 7 install with a different domain and web directory. I've changed `base_url` in `settings.php` and it does nothing and `RewriteBase` in `.htaccess` and it does nothing. I flushed all caches. I even changed to a basic theme. None if it made any difference. I'm stumped and about to resort to outputting variables from core. Any help?

With the duplicate sub directory in the URL, or without it, confusingly enough, the node does display and everything works. What is going on?

Comment: I found another lead it only seems to do this if i put in the l() function on a template "node/$node->nid" but even "/node/$node->nid" makes the duplicate subdirectory in the URL go away hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I installed pathauto to try and force it to work and realized that the url aliases set on every node had content/ prepended to them as part of a mass import.

I ran this in the mysql console to update them correctly:

```
update url_alias set alias = REPLACE(alias,'content/node','node');
```

And problem fixed.